# Delphi 7 - error when get values using sql operator in

Tags: sql, delphi, in-operator

Got no answer on related thread, so i make this question. I've been searched for how to retrieve records value using where clause with multiple values and i got this.

table example :

```
|ID |PRICE|
|1  |3000 |
|2  |2000 |
|3  |1000 |
|4  |5000 |
|5  |4000 |
```

SQL query :

```
DM.Zread.Close;
DM.Zread.SQL.CommaText := 'select PRICE from DVD where ID in (1, 2, 3)';
DM.Zread.Open;
```

Above gave me an error, when i only put one 1 values which is (1) or (2) it's works fine.

Questions are :

1. how to straight it, so i could get the values from 3 different
   records ?
2. how to apply it on string values instead ?

Comment: For future reference, when you get an error and want help: please don't tell us "_it gave me an error_". Tell us the ***actual error message***.

Comment: Thank you for telling me the right thing. i think that's why i got my rep reduced and your provided code great, it's work fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`SQL` is a `TStrings` subclass. When you set `CommaText` using the above, you are actually setting your query to:

```
select PRICE from DVD where ID in (1
2
3)
```

This obviously won't work.
You want to set the `Text` property or use `Add()` method to add separate lines.

Answer (score 0):

Try using **CommandText** rather than **CommaText** on your SQL call

```
DM.Zread.Close;
DM.Zread.SQL.CommaText := 'select PRICE from DVD where ID in (1, 2, 3)';
DM.Zread.Open;


DM.Zread.SQL.CommandText := 'select PRICE from DVD where ID in (1, 2, 3)';
```

Comment: i tried to use CommandText instead, but it says `undecleared identifier`

Comment: Perhaps you are thinking of TClienDataSet, which has a CommandText property.

Comment: -1, this is not the solution to the question, it's an incorrect assumption.